# Local copy of array Element

Tags: c++, arrays

To make my code more readable, i have a local variable inside a function, that takes a specified element from an array, like this:

```
Element* elements = new Element[10];

void doSomething(int index) {
    Element element = elements[index];
    // do things with that element
}
```

What happens here: is element an independent copy of elements[index] that gets destroyed at the end of the function? From what I've tested, it seems like it, as changes in element don't affect element[index], however, I'd like to know what's happening behind the scenes. Does the assignment of element call an implicit copy constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what happens (although this is an initialisation, not an assignment).

You've declared `Element` to be an object, so it's a separate object from any other `Element`. It's initialised by copying its initialiser `elements[index]`. If you haven't delcared a copy-constructor, then it uses the implicit one, copying each member.

If you wanted to modify the element in the array, then you'd want a reference:

```
Element & element = elements[index];
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the local variable "element" is independent of global "elements pointer".
Changes in local value will not change the global value.